# how to disable the controlls and pausing behavior on click in cocoa?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, video

In m project I have a window with a QuickTime Movie View
object in the center. I've configured the Movie View to not show any
controls (Play, Pause, Stop etc.). I can load and play a movie fine through
code. When a user clicks on the move that is playing, the movie pauses.

Is there a way to disable this pausing behavior?

Comment: Do you know the sulution for this?

Comment: what do u mean?  I want answer for my question guys.. not the dummy links

Comment: i did it by puting an empty view in the top of the Quicktime movie View

Comment: @touti i accept your answer.. i tried that but the movie still pauses.. how to add another view on movieview?